# Find out if form element is required in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, element, required

Is there any way in Zend Framework 1.10 to find out whether a form element has been defined as required?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I wrote my question in a rush and didn't add that info.

I started trying $form->element->getRequired(), which seems to work in newer versions of ZF, but not in 1.10. Then, based on some solutions in other forums, i tried $form->element->required, and from then on, basically I tried everything I could think of, no matter how random it seemed.
doydoy44 already solved my question below, but you were right at asking me for details so I felt I had to reply to your question, and besides I think it was a bad example to other people asking a question and not explaining what I had already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isRequired()` method like this:

```
$form = new Application_Form_Yourform();
$elts_required = [];
foreach ($form->getElements() as $elt){
    if ($elt->isRequired())
       $elts_required[] = $elt->getName();
}
var_dump($elts_required);
```

Comment: Thank you, I spent a lot of time trying to find out.